# Align a Span and Heading within card-header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to style Bootsrap 4's `card-header` so that there is a heading and span vertically aligned on same line. The header should consist of a `<hX>` heading for expanding `card`'s `card-body` and a `<span>` which is non-clicable and pulled to the right:
[image: align-items-baseline]
How can I ensure the "Non-clicable body summary" span appear on **same line** as the "Clicable header"?

```css
.card-header h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
    <div class="float-right card-summary">Non-clicable body summary</div>
    <a class="mb-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse">
      <h3>
        Clicable header
      </h3>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="collapse" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use flexbox instead of floating and I think it would help you align h3 and span vertically: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
.card-header h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card">
  <div class="align-items-center card-header d-flex justify-content-between" id="headingOne">
    <a class="mb-0" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse">
      <h3>
        Clicable header
      </h3>
    </a>
    <div class="card-summary">Non-clicable body summary</div>
  </div>

  <div id="collapse" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p>Some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Removed floats and used default BS flexbox utility classes for
>   section.

Comment: Yes, this answers my question - I will be accepting this answer in 5 mins.

Comment: Just add class `mb-0` in `<h3>` to vertically center both the elements. Currently looking slightly misaligned.

Answer (score 1):

first remove  `float-right` class.

you can use the  `d-flex justify-content-between` class in `card-header` div.

```
<div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between"  id="headingOne">
```

and also add `align-self-center` class.  `<div class="card-summary align-self-center">Non-clicable body summary</div>`

**[Working Demo](https://codepen.io/uidesigner/pen/drNMKr)**

> Ref : **[Bootstrap utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/)**